# Detaching firestore listener in python causes program to freeze

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is simple test code where listener getting attached to document in firestore and after that getting detached.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('Path to your credential file')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'Received document snapshot: {}'.format(doc.id))

db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection('cities').document('SF')

doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)  # attaching listener

print('unsubscribing')
doc_watch.unsubscribe() # detaching listener
print('unsubscribed')
```

Listener works well but when it comes to detaching, the program just freezes at unsubscribe() call. It doesn't give any error or exception and after some time situation is same. Only making keyboard interrupt stops program and I get every time the same traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firestore_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    doc_watch.unsubscribe()
  File "/home/andriy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/watch.py", line 313, in unsubscribe
    self.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/andriy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/watch.py", line 278, in close                                                                                                                             
    self._consumer.stop()                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/andriy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py", line 701, in stop                                                                                                                                         
    self._thread.join()                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1056, in join                                                                                                                                                                                
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock                                                                                                                                                               
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):                                                                                                                                                                                                      
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: This is an open issue, see https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/9008

Comment: It was recently fixed and closed. How can I get newer version of python client with this fix? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, unfortunately. For now, I would leave out `unsubscribe()` until the next release. Otherwise, I think this might describe how to use library from github? https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst#using-a-development-checkout

Comment: When I tried to use library from github I noticed that there is new version of google-api-core. And with new version(1.14.3) unsubscribe works.
Thank you much